# Loop over a list and copy a file if that file exists locally only

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

my playbook uses 2 external files:

- 1 file that holds the username and other variables:

```
  - name: jimi
    status: present
    sudo: "yes"
```

- 1 file inside `files/jimi.pub` that holds the user's public key

```
-rw-rw-rw- 1 root root   0 Jul 19 10:45 jimi.pub
```

My playbook will create the user and copy the key, but if a user doesn't have the key file inside `files/username.pub` it will error out. My end goal is to copy the key **only** if the key file exists and if not, continue on to the next user in the list.

I can stat the file locally, but since it will loop over the users list, it will ultimately find a user without a key and error out.

Here is how the key file copy looks like:

```
  - name: Setting the authorized key for users
    authorized_key:
      user: "{{ item.name }}"
      key: "{{ lookup('file', 'files/'+ item.name + '.pub') }}"
      state: "{{ item.status }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
```

How can I copy the key **only** if the key file exists and if not, continue on to the next user in the list without having the playbook error out!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Local files can be easily tested. See [Testing paths](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths). For example, given the users

```yaml
    users: [alice, bob, jimi]
```

and the files

```sh
shell> ls -1 files/
bob.pub
jimi.pub
```

The task

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: "Setting the authorized key for {{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ users }}"
      vars:
        _file: "files/{{ item }}.pub"
      when: _file is exists
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] **************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item=alice) 
ok: [localhost] => (item=bob) => 
  msg: Setting the authorized key for bob
ok: [localhost] => (item=jimi) => 
  msg: Setting the authorized key for jimi
```

These [tests](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-paths) always provide information about a path on the controller e.g. they are independent of the host the task is running at.

Comment: its a step closer, but somehow it doesn't add the correct key for each user..
   `- name: Setting the authorized key for users`
    `authorized_key:`
      `user: "{{ item.name }}"`
      `key: "{{ _file }}"`
      `state: "{{ item.status }}"`
    `loop: "{{ users }}"`
    `vars:`
      `_file: "files/{{ item.name }}.pub"`
     `when: _file is exists`